# how can I set the bin centre values of histogram myself?

Tags: r, histogram, distribution

Lets say I have a data frame like below

```
mat <- data.frame(matrix(data = rexp(200, rate = 10), nrow = 100, ncol = 10))
```

Which then I can calculate the histogram on each of them columns using

```
matAllCols <- apply(mat, 2, hist)
```

Now if you look at matAllCols$breaks , you can see sometimes 11, sometimes 12 etc.
what I want is to set a threshold for it. for example it should always be 12 and the distances between each bin centre (which is stored as matAllCols$mids) be 0.01

Doing it for one column at the time seems to be simple, but when I tried to do it for all columns, it does not work. also this is only breaks, how to set the mids is also not straightforward

```
matAllCols <- apply(mat, 2, function(x) hist(x , breaks = 12))
```

is there anyway to do this ?

Comment: maybe by taking a tea and looking at the documentation ? https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html  You can mention the break parameter you are looking for.

Comment: @Colonel Beauvel   for example I tired matAllCols <- apply(mat, 2, function(x) hist(x , breaks = 12))  but does not work

Comment: Hidden in `?hist` concerning breaks: `In the last three cases the number is a suggestion only; the breakpoints will be set to pretty values. If breaks is a function, the x vector is supplied to it as the only argument.`

Comment: @Christoph do you have any suggestion ? to be honest I don't get it

Comment: You are using the plot function `hist` - right? I had the same problem and the `hist`-help tells you that `hist` overrules you. I think when I truncated my data to the region of interest, it worked ok. If you can supply some test data I can have a look at it.

Comment: @Christoph an example data is given above in my question! it is not good one?

Comment: `set.seed(1); mat <- data.frame(matrix(data = rexp(200, rate = 10), nrow = 100, ncol = 10))` 
`range(mat) # [1] 0.002025041 0.483281274` 
`matAllCols <- apply(mat, 2, function(x) hist(x , breaks = seq(0, 0.52, 0.04)))`  All of breaks are 14 and the distances are 0.04. Is this what you want ?

Comment: @crayfish44 yes that is what i wanted, put it as an answer if you like so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the probrem by giving the all breakpoints between histogram cells as `breaks`. (**But** this is written in [stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html) as @Colonel Beauvel said)

```
set.seed(1); mat <- data.frame(matrix(data = rexp(200, rate = 10), nrow = 100, ncol = 10))
# You need to check the data range to decide the breakpoints.
range(mat) # [1] 0.002025041 0.483281274
# You can set the breakpoints manually.
matAllCols <- apply(mat, 2, function(x) hist(x , breaks = seq(0, 0.52, 0.04)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- data.frame(matrix(data = rexp(200, rate = 10), nrow = 100, ncol = 10))
matAllCols <- apply(mat, 2, function(x) hist(x , breaks = seq(0, 0.5, 0.05)))
```

or simply

```
x <- rexp(200, rate = 10)
hist(x[x>=0 & x <=0.5] , breaks = seq(0, 0.5, 0.05))
```